# ¿Cómo puedo hacer rotar un menu de comedor?

Tags: javascript

Tengo un HTML que tiene que mostrar en pantalla el menu diario. El mismo no está asignado al dia sino que son 8 platos que se van sucediendo uno tras otros (menu 1, menu 2, menu3...) sin importar el dia, aunque sean sabados y domingos

```
<div>
  <h3>MENU DEL DIA</h3>
</div>
<div>
  <h5>ENTRADA</h5>
  <p id="entrada"></p>
  <br>
  <h5>PLATO</h5>
  <p id="plato"></p>
  <br>
  <h5>POSTRE</h5>
  <p id="postre"></p>
  <br>
</div>
```

Hice varios arreglos con el contenido del menu para que los muestre, obviamente el que defino en la constante me lo muestra, pero no se como hacer para que vayan actualizandose dia a dia.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 let menu_1 = ["Ensalada","Pollo al horno con papas","Flan"];
 let menu_2 = ["Ensalada de lechuga y repollo bicolor","Milanesa de carne con Puré mixto","Fruta"];
 let menu_3 = ["Ensalada de remolacha y zanahoria","Pastel de Papas","Fruta"];
 let menu_4 = ["Ensalada de zanahoria y tomate","Milanesa de pollo con pure amarillo","Arrollado"];
 let menu_5 = ["Ensalada de lechuga y repollo bicolor","Pizza y empanadas de carne","Fruta"];
 let menu_6 = ["Ensalada fresca","Tarta de Jamon y Queso","Fruta"];
 let menu_7 = ["Tortilla de verdura","Milanesa de pollo con papa perejilada","postre de chocolate"];
 let menu_8 = ["Ensalada de lechuga y zanahoria","Fideos con bolognesa","Fruta"];
  
 const mostrarEntrada = document.getElementById('entrada')
 mostrarEntrada.innerText = menu_5 [0];
 const mostrarPlato = document.getElementById('plato')
 mostrarPlato.innerText = menu_5 [1];
 const mostrarPostre = document.getElementById('postre')
 mostrarPostre.innerText = menu_5 [2];
});
```

Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varias formas de realizar lo que pedís, yo tengo esta que a decir verdad es bastante enderezada:

Primero, definimos los menú como una array multidimensional (arrays adentro de otra array):

```
let menu = [
["Ensalada","Pollo al horno con papas","Flan"],
["Ensalada de lechuga y repollo bicolor","Milanesa de carne con Puré mixto","Fruta"],
["Ensalada de remolacha y zanahoria","Pastel de Papas","Fruta"],
["Ensalada de zanahoria y tomate","Milanesa de pollo con pure amarillo","Arrollado"],
["Ensalada de lechuga y repollo bicolor","Pizza y empanadas de carne","Fruta"],
["Ensalada fresca","Tarta de Jamon y Queso","Fruta"],
["Tortilla de verdura","Milanesa de pollo con papa perejilada","postre de chocolate"],
["Ensalada de lechuga y zanahoria","Fideos con bolognesa","Fruta"]
]
```

Después vamos a definir otra array multidimensional que separa los 365 días del año en 8 diferentes grupos (un grupo para cada menú)

```
let gruposDeDias = [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]
let x = 0;
for (let i = 1; i<366 ; i++){
    gruposDeDias[x].push(i)
    x++;
    if(x === 8) x = 0;
}
```

Luego, definimos una variable que nos diga a que grupo pertenece el día del año en el que nos encontrmos hoy:

```
var fecha = new Date()
let diaDelAño = Math.floor((Date.now()/(1000*60*60*24))-(365*(fecha.getFullYear()-1970))-((fecha.getFullYear()-1970)/4)) //Día del año en el que estamos
let menuDelDia;
for(let i = 0; i<8; i++){
    if(gruposDeDias[i].indexOf(diaDelAño) !== -1) menuDelDia = i;
}
```

Y por último, dependiendo del grupo de días en el que nos encontramos imprimimos un menu de nuestra array multidimensional

```
const mostrarEntrada = document.getElementById('entrada')
mostrarEntrada.innerText = menu[menuDelDia][0];
const mostrarPlato = document.getElementById('plato')
mostrarPlato.innerText = menu [menuDelDia][1];
const mostrarPostre = document.getElementById('postre')
mostrarPostre.innerText = menu [menuDelDia][2];
```

*Aclaro: mis conocimientos son escasos y probablemente este código pueda ser mucho más limpio, por favor comentarme como puede ser mejorado*

Comment: Muchísimas Gracias, me resulto perfecto